# is x509 certificate signed by ca valid?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, x.509

I've got certificate 'sample cert' which is valid to '2015-12-31' but it was signed by root CA certificate. But when it was signing CA cert was valid to 2015-06-30'. So my question is, is today (2015-07-01) 'sample cert' is valid and can be used to validation of sign or not?

Another way as I understand you can form this question is "Can CA have more than one root CA with the same DN record"?

Answer (score 1):

It depended on the root CA's and it's connection with another CA's. However generally in client authentication, you show your certificate to it, it will check this certificate parent's since it get the root CA. And what happen if the root CA certificate not valid? 
I think you should report this problem to support team of that CA.

Comment: ok, but i was thinking obaout fake CA - myself + openSSL:) My problem is that, that i have a tool for verification of signatures and as in parameters i should pass signature and ca certs, but it says thah DN record od both certs are thesame and thats error. I want to know is that really error?